# When Clear the Cache Storage it throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, key, browser-cache

```
   useEffect(async () => {
    caches.open('my-cache')
  }, [token, user_id])
```

When i try to logout my application

```
const logoutFunc = () => {
    localStorage.clear()
    caches.keys().then((list) =>
       list.map((key) => {
       caches.delete(key)
       router.push('/')
    })
)
```

When it runs, it throws error like,

[image]

Cache cleared. but it throws error

Comment: Where does `caches` come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error by adding a catch block to your code.

```js
caches.keys().then((list) =>
   list.map((key) => {
   caches.delete(key)
   router.push('/')
}).catch(e => ...)
```

For a solution, you can remove the asynchronous function in useEffect and [read the article](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect).

```js
useEffect(async () => {
     caches.open('my-cache')
   }, [token, user_id])
```